# Landing Page Built with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have had a landing page built for me which is fairly simple layout. But the problem is the Banner Photo is swamping the page and I have to scroll to see completed page. Is there an adjustment I can make to HTML and/or CSS to reduce the height of the banner photo by about a third?

Comment: We need to see some code to help you here.

Comment: Sorry I thought Bootstrap was a standard framework and therefore anyone that knows it would know the solution. Assuming there is one of course. I wouldn't know which bit of the code to paste in.

Comment: Bootstrap is a pretty much popular framework, but we don't know your exact setup. You could create a code snippet of the header, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Carl Bootstrap is a standard framework but when someone designs something in Bootstrap it's possible for them to manually override the CSS - it doesn't cover everything.

Comment: Ok thanks Sam. I can't attach the files and there isn't enough room to paste all the code. I'll have to see if I can pick it up off Google. Thanks again.

Comment: Does this help as a starter?<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-block">
     <img class="img-responsive " src="img/top-banner.jpg" width="100%">
    </div>

Comment: The image should be in the background of your header or something like that, right?

Comment: Hi Paul from what I can see the top line of site which contains logo and contact details underneath which is the image I refer to are under the <head><\head> block in the html but are in the body. Under the image are 4 more smaller images in line followed by text. I will paste body code in next comment.

Comment: Scrap that thought far too much code!

Comment: You might want to create a fiddle on something like https://jsfiddle.net/. You can also add the bootstrap library on the left side of the page.

Comment: So stupid of me! https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlLyoyc8XoHxk5d2pc16TXAe2BFmhw one drive link to files

Comment: No worries, all of us started out some time ago. I added one possible approach as an answer. Hope this fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches of doing this. I'll just show you one, that should perfectly fit your current page and needs.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex align-items-end overflow-hidden banner-image-container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/top-banner.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

(Inside your `<style` tag:)

```
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-image-container {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

What I did is to limit the container around your image to a maximum height of 400px. Because your image is bigger then that, I added `overflow: hidden;` to the container, so it will cut the rest of the image off. Now your main focus in the image will be the building I guess. So I did move it all the way to the top with `d-flex align-items-end`.

Comment: Top notch Paul. Thanks you very much. Appreciated.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped. If this is the "correct answer" to your question, you can flag it with the green checkmark next to my answer.